# How to affect displaying of list with for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, display

I am trying to display a list of temperature conversions using loops or any other basic method. Please keep it very basic; no imports. 
This is the code I have now:

```
temperature_list = [[-10,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
                [-23.33,-17.78,-12.22,-6.67,-1.11,4.44,10,15.56,21.11,26.67,32.22,37.78]]


for farenheit in range(12):
    print ('Farenheit:',temperature_list[0][farenheit])

for celsius in range(12):
    print('Celsius:', temperature_list[1][celsius])
```

Now, what I'd like to display is Fahrenheit then it's corresponding Celsius conversion right after. With this code it only displays all Fahrenheit first then all the Celsius. I don't quite understand how to line them up to display Fahrenheit value then Celsius value and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
temperature_list = [[-10,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
                [-23.33,-17.78,-12.22,-6.67,-1.11,4.44,10,15.56,21.11,26.67,32.22,37.78]]


for temperature in range(12):
    print ('Farenheit:',temperature_list[0][temperature])
    print('Celsius:', temperature_list[1][temperature])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`:

```
temperature_list = [[-10,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100], 
                    [-23.33,-17.78,-12.22,-6.67,-1.11,4.44,10,15.56,21.11,26.67,32.22,37.78]]

for f, t in zip(temperature_list[0], temperature_list[1]):
    print('Farenheit: {}, Celsius: {}'.format(f, t))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sequence unpacking and `zip` with f-strings (Python 3.6+):

```
far, celsius = [[-10,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
                [-23.33,-17.78,-12.22,-6.67,-1.11,4.44,10,15.56,21.11,26.67,32.22,37.78]]

for f, c in zip(far, celsius):
    print(f'Farenheit: {f}, Celsius: {c}')

Farenheit: -10, Celsius: -23.33
Farenheit: 0, Celsius: -17.78
Farenheit: 10, Celsius: -12.22
Farenheit: 20, Celsius: -6.67
Farenheit: 30, Celsius: -1.11
Farenheit: 40, Celsius: 4.44
Farenheit: 50, Celsius: 10
Farenheit: 60, Celsius: 15.56
Farenheit: 70, Celsius: 21.11
Farenheit: 80, Celsius: 26.67
Farenheit: 90, Celsius: 32.22
Farenheit: 100, Celsius: 37.78
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to print both sublists in the same loop. If you want to print them in the same string - use the `format()` method. Curved brackets in a string define the place for values of a `format()` arguments.

```
for i in range(12):
    print('{} F = {} C'.format(temperature_list[0][i], temperature_list[1][i]))
```

you also might find use for the dictionaries:

```
temperature_list = {'farenheit':[1, ... , 500], 'celcius':[23, ..., 329]} #numbers are just for the example, no real farenheit/celsius accordance
print(temperature_list['farenheit'][0])
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to understand how the loops are working, your loop 1 i.e. the loop displaying Farenheit is displaying all the content of temperature_list[0][0....11]
then the second loop is displaying all the content of temperature_list[1][0....11]
and what you want to display is something like this:

Farenheit: temperature_list[0][0]  Celsius: temperature_list[1][0]

Farenheit: temperature_list[0][1]  Celsius: temperature_list[1][1]

Farenheit: temperature_list[0][2] Celsius:  temperature_list[1][2]

.

.

.

.

Farenheit: temperature_list[0][11] Celsius:   temperature_list[1][11]

So you simply need to use a single loop. Replace your code with

```
temperature_list = [[-10,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
            [-23.33,-17.78,-12.22,-6.67,-1.11,4.44,10,15.56,21.11,26.67,32.22,37.78]]
for temperature in range(12):
     print ('Farenheit:',temperature_list[0][temperature])
     print('Celsius:', temperature_list[1][temperature])
```

Hope this will help you understand a bit better!

Comment: Don't give similar answers

Comment: Haven't looked at other answers!

Comment: you should because it is community; not personal chat.

Comment: I am glad to know that!